Issue with low odometry publish rate in ROS 2 Foxy
Description
I am experiencing an issue with my robot's odometry publish rate in ROS 2 Foxy, which I have to use due to hardware setup. Despite setting the publish_rate parameter to 60 Hz, the actual publish rate of the /odom topic remains around 5.5 Hz. My setup involves a differential drive robot using ros2_control. Below are the details of my configuration and steps I have taken to debug the issue.
Here is the config file
robot_base_controller:
  type: "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  publish_rate: 60 
  left_wheel: "left_wheel_joint"
  right_wheel: "right_wheel_joint"
  cmd_vel_timeout: 0.5
  base_frame_id: "base_link"
  odom_frame_id: "odom"
  use_stamped_vel: false
  open_loop: false
  # other parameters 


Debugging

ros2 param get /robot_base_controller publish_rate confirms the publish_rate is set to 60 Hz. Despite that, its effect is not showing up. The rate at which /odom is published remains around 5.5 Hz confirmed with ros2 topic hz /odom.
The issue does not seem to be due to limited resources on the robot's computer (NVIDIA Xavier NX), confirmed with top.

Request for help
I seek advice on what might be causing the low publish rate of the /odom topic and how to ensure it publishes at the desired rate of 60 Hz. It does not seem to be of any effect. Can it be a missed feature or bug in Foxy? Any insights or suggestions for further debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Be aware that Foxy is EOL since quite a long time now. Why exactly do you have to use it?
Some ideas:

What is the update rate of the controller_manger? This is the general upper limit.
If you hardware component is blocking the realtime loop, everything will run slower.
Have you tried to set it to something lower, e.g., 1Hz? Does it affect the update rate?


I use ROS 2 Foxy, despite its EOL, because the robot has the NVIDIA Xavier platform, which runs Ubuntu 20.04 as its latest board support package (BSP) version.
The update rate of the controller_manager is set to 40 Hz.
I tried setting it lower (like 1 or 2 Hz) as suggested. It goes down but does not go up.
It is possible the hardware component is blocking the realtime loop. Can you please suggest how to investigate this further?
Thank you!

you could try to run the ROS stack in a docker container with a newer Ubuntu. But this depends which hardware resources you need and how you can use that inside the docker.

ad realtime-loop: you have to investigate the read/write methods of your hardware component. There is no built-in tool for performance testing available. But at this low update rate, you could even use streaming text/logger in the console.

I started profiling and found that CPU and Memory utilization are around 50% when the robot is operating and all processing is happening. The controller_manager's CPU utilization is around 12.5%, which does not represent a bottleneck. Would you like to suggest other things to look deeper into?

I will carefully examine the read/write methods. I am sure the calls to the CAN interface to retrieve data are blocking. I will create a separate communication thread and let the read/write process update the values. Please share with me other suggestions or recommendations you may think of. Thank you!
